# Grouping Query Data - MySQL

Tags: php, sql, grouping

I've following data in mySQL:(This is Comment data)
[image: SQL Data]

and then I wanna group those data by ucom_ucom_id, and it'll be like this

```
UCOM_ID | USER_ID |  UCOM_DATE | UCOM_COMMENT | UCOM_TITLE | UCOM_UCOM_ID
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
   7    |    2    | 2012-01-28 | xxx          | xxx        | 0
   8    |    2    | 2012-01-28 | xxx          | xxx        | 7
  12    |    2    | 2012-01-28 | xxx          | xxx        | 7
   9    |    2    | 2012-01-28 | xxx          | xxx        | 0
  13    |    2    | 2012-01-28 | xxx          | xxx        | 9
```

Which `UCOM_UCOM_ID = 0, is first comment`, and `if UCOM_UCOM_ID = one of UCOM_ID`, then it is comment from first comment.
I would like to produce view in php like this:

```
[UCOM_ID] 7, [UCOM_COMMENT] xxx
             [UCOM_ID]  8, [UCOM_COMMENT] xxx
             [UCOM_ID] 12, [UCOM_COMMENT] xxx

[UCOM_ID] 9, [UCOM_COMMENT] xxx
             [UCOM_ID] 13, [UCOM_COMMENT] xxx
```

What query in mySql to get the result above, or should I do anything else without using query,.?
Many Thanks,.

Comment: use group by  `ucom_ucom_id` ..**NOTE:** you have to remove any column that makes grouping  unworkable  like  `UCOM_ID` .

Comment: @jjj, sorry I still don't understand, can you tell more specific.? I've try this `SELECT * FROM user_comments group by ucom_ucom_id` but the result is only 3 rows ([UCOM_ID] 7, 8, 13)

Comment: You can't use SELECT * when you are using GROUP BY unless you put every field into the group by clause and if you do that then you're not really grouping. That is to say, * and GROUP BY are essentially incompatible.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little tough to tell exactly what you intend the result set to look like. I think this will probably do what you want though:

```
SELECT  y.UCOM_ID, y.UCOM_COMMENT
FROM    tablename x
    LEFT JOIN   tablename y
        ON  y.UCOM_UCOM_ID = x.UCOM_ID
            OR
            (y.UCOM_UCOM_ID = 0
             AND
             y.UCOM_ID = x.UCOM_ID)
WHERE   x.UCOM_UCOM_ID = 0
```

Comment: ah, I just realized I left out a )... fixed